# Орфографическая ошибка в справке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> [image: скриншот ошибки]

В справке по ответам в первом же абзаце раздела ["как написать хороший ответ"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ошибка. Слово "бескорыстно" написано с буквой З.

Comment: лучше вставить проблемный текст в цитате и добавить ссылку на страницу с ошибкой вместо огромной картинки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил эту ошибку и ещё ряд пунктуационных, заменил дефисы на тире. Проверяйте. :)

Comment: Отлично! Я не специалист по пунктуации, но сейчас она выглядит грамотно. В разделе "Ответ на вопрос" вместо "о всех" нужно написать "[обо всех](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE)".

Comment: @Mae спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Энтузиасты русского языка [рекомендовали](http://rus.stackexchange.com/a/428525/184482) поставить запятую перед тире в этом месте: ["это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего, — проголосуйте за ответы"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), или заменить это тире на двоеточие.